# Sencha Touch 2 Draggable

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have the following in a Container

```
    { direction:'vertical',
              constraint: {
                min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                max: { x: 0, y: 338 }
              },
              listeners: {

                    drag: function( draggable, evt, offsetX, offsetY, eOpts ) {
                         console.log( offsetX);
                       // Ext.getCmp("twitterList").setTop(10);
                    }

              }
}
```

I am looking to somehow change the position of the container being dragged to show with an animation from bottom to top?

Tried with setTop but doesn't work. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Ext.get("twitterList").setTop(10);
```